# Detect How User Logs in on PFLoginViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, pfloginviewcontroller

I am trying to determine how a user logs in using Parse, either signing in with username and password, logging in with Facebook, or login in with Twitter.  I have in my delegate method

```
- (void)logInViewController:(PFLogInViewController *)logInController didLogInUser:(PFUser *)user {
    BOOL isLinkedToTwitter = [PFTwitterUtils isLinkedWithUser:[PFUser currentUser]];
    BOOL isLinkedToFacebook = [PFFacebookUtils isLinkedWithUser:[PFUser currentUser]];
    if (isLinkedToFacebook) {
//Facebook
NSLog(@"Facebook");
}
if (isLinkedToTwitter) {
//Twitter
NSLog(@"Twitter");
}
else {
//Normal
NSLog(@"Regular Login");
}
```

The issue is that the `else` tag is being fired every time.  If I login with Facebook, I get the Facebook `NSLog` and the Regular one.  If I login with Twitter I get the Twitter `NSLog` and the regular one.  What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your second `if` to `else if` so that it only triggers one of the options

```
    if (isLinkedToFacebook) {
        //Facebook
        NSLog(@"Facebook");
    } else if (isLinkedToTwitter) {
       //Twitter
       NSLog(@"Twitter");
    } else {
      //Normal
      NSLog(@"Regular Login");
    }
```